# ComplexType Model

Tags: xml, model, xsd, complextype

I am entirely new to XML Schema and am trying to get the basics down. 
Here is the Model of ComplexType. I do not understand, how i can read the Content Part. The Questions ist, wich element can the ComplexType contain).

```
<complexType
  abstract = Boolean : false 
  block = (#all | List of (extension | restriction))
  final = (#all | List of (extension | restriction))
  id = ID 
  mixed = Boolean : false
  name = NCName 
  {any attributes with non-schema Namespace...}>
Content: (annotation?, (simpleContent | complexContent | ((group | all | 
choice | sequence)?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?))))
</complexType>
```

The following Symbols or Operators ar in the Model Syntax in the complexType

```
?            = ( one or no of this element) 
*            = ( several or no of this element) 
no operator  = (  does mean one of this element) 
|            = ( is this e OR ? )
```

i tried the following combination,
it is possible:

```
annotation, simpleContent
simpleContent
annotation, complexContent
complexContent
```

In the following combinations, could we place instead of sequence, also
this elemens, groupe, all, choice ( and i ignored the anyAttribut element)

```
annotation,sequence,attributeA,attributeB,attributeGroupeA
sequence,attributeA,attributeB,attributeGroupeA
attributeA,attributeB,attributeGroupeA
attributeA
attributeGroupeA
```

As we cann see it is possible to have this combination, attributeA,attributeB,attributeGroupeA and this is the point in my concept in wiche i dont
understand in the Model the Syntax.

```
((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?))
```

Because of the | Symbol it should not be possible to have the following combinations

```
attributeA,attributeB,attributeGroupeA
```

What i do read wrong ?

```
(attribute | attributeGroup)*
```

This Syntax does mean for me. i have the following possibilites of combinations

```
attributeA,attributeB
attribute
attributeGroupeA,attriubteGroupeB
attributeGroupeA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `(attribute | attributeGroup)` as allowing either `attribute` or `attributeGroup`.

Read `(attribute | attributeGroup)*` as allowing zero or more of `attribute` or `attributeGroup`.  Each time you go back for another possible occurrence of an `attribute` or `attributeGroup`, you may again choose either one.  Therefore, **this construct allows an arbitrary sequence of zero or more `attribute` or `attributeGroup` *in any order*.**

So, in full XML Schema terms, for example, the following `Type` definition is supported by the BNF for `complexType`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">

  <xs:attributeGroup name="AttributeGroupXY1">
    <xs:attribute name="attributeX1"/>
    <xs:attribute name="attributeY1"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <xs:attributeGroup name="AttributeGroupXY2">
    <xs:attribute name="attributeX2"/>
    <xs:attribute name="attributeY2"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <xs:complexType name="Type">
    <xs:attribute name="attributeA"/>
    <xs:attribute name="attributeB"/>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="AttributeGroupXY1"/>
    <xs:attribute name="attributeC"/>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="AttributeGroupXY2"/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Hi tanks, i will start Question again because my problem is more how to read the Syntax, this was my first Question, thanks, i am new in this Formu